# c# .Net Core 3.1 Azure App Service Windows - Application not able to retrieve App settings

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, web-applications, configuration

I am having issues with .Net core 3.1 app not behaving properly as the way it should.
I can run the app fine on my local machine.
I have added custom authorization on the app which runs fine on my local machine.
After i deploy the app into Azure App Service and use App Settings to configure the variables and restart the app and test it, authorization fails.

In my Startup class in Configureservices method in am reading app settings with Configuration["Appsettings:Authorization"].
On my local machine this value is coming from appsettings.json.
All good till.

After I deploy the app to Azure, create app settings (please see screen shot)and restart the application and test, I get unAuthorize message.
[image: Azure app settings]

To troubleshoot it I redeployed the application to Azure now but included appsettings.json and it now the app is working fine.

I would like to know if Configuration["Appsettings:Authorization"] is right way to read Azure App settings or I am doing something wrong here.
Please advise.

Comment: Add your `appsettings.json` in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think.

*To troubleshoot it I redeployed the application to Azure now but included appsettings.json and it now the app is working fine.*

This means, your app settings are fine, and the way you have deployed is also fine. We can eliminate the possibility that something is wrong with the way you have deployed or setup the deployment.

*I would like to know if Configuration["Appsettings:Authorization"] is right way to read Azure App settings or I am doing something wrong here. Please advise.*

This is the correct way of doing it. Also, the settings are being read fine (when you include appsettings.json) on both local running, and web app deployment.

(for example, i have a auth app deployed here - https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/APIServerDotNetCoreWithAuth0/blob/master/dotnetcoreapiserverwithauth0/Startup.cs ) which does the exact same thing you are doing.

*how to solve?*

step 1 - for now, if its really urgent, keep the appsettings.json in your main app, so that your customers/company is not affected.

step 2 - setup another web app, like a test web app or a staging web app or something, give it a go again. I believe, when you are configuring the app with the appsetting values, you are making a mistake.

Comment: Hi @Jay i check Azure App service settings which is a JSON array  -you can see this by clicking advanced settings under configurations -> application settings->advanced edit. So I have to change my appsettings from a nested JSON to a simple JSON like {"Authorization":"value","Client":"value"} from {"Appsettings":{"Authorization":":"value"}} and in my code read it as Configuration["Authorization"] and i redeployed the code and its working now. I understand appsettings.json is good for local development but  I can't find a relevant document that explains this even from Microsoft end.

Comment: glad you got it working. about the JSON format, well, you know, things can be very fluid with these tiny details with the microsoft docs. A lot of times, its all trial and error and experimenting with these cloud things :)